# Show that every singleton is open in $\mathcal{T}_\#$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{T}_\#$ be a family so that $U\in\mathcal{T}_\#$ if $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and its intersection with all lines that are parallel to either of the axes is open in the euclidean topology of that line. Now let $Y = \{(t, \frac1n t:t\in\mathbb{R},n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}\}$. Show that every singleton $\{y\}\subset Y\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is open.
I tried an approach where for a point $x$ I consider an open set of all points within a circle around it, and then remove all points that are on the same line as $x$ and $(0,0)$ except $x$. I then tried intersecting that with some other open sets, but got nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y\in Y\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ be an arbitrary point. Then $y=(t,\frac tn)$ for some non-zero $t$ and positive integer $n$. Denote a straight line $\{(t’, \frac tn):t\in\Bbb R\}$ by $\ell$. Let $D$ be an open disc centered at $y$ so small that it is disjoint from $Y\setminus\ell$. It is easy to see that $O_y=D\setminus\ell $ is an open neigborhood of the point $y$ in $\mathcal{T}_\#$, and $O_y\cap Y=\{y\}$.